# update Firebase data using Polymer's firebase-collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I am using a firebase-collection element to fetch an array of objects from my Firebase repository in a Polymer application. The data fetches with no problem. Now that I have the objects, how do I update a child property on one of them?

```
<firebase-collection
  id="myfb"
  location="https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs"
  data="{{dinosaurs}}">
</firebase-collection>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[dinosaurs]]" as="dinosaur">
  <h4>[[dinosaur.__firebaseKey__]]</h4>
  Height: <span>[[dinosaur.height]]</span>
  <iron-icon on-click="updateDino"></iron-icon>
</template>
```

... polymer boilerplate omitted for brevity ...

```
updateDino: function(e) {
   var key = e.model.dinosaur.__firebaseKey__;

   // now what? 
   // tried this: e.model.dinosaur.height = 3.1415 
   // but firebase doesn't save the change. 

   // also tried various things with this.$.myfb.add but 
   // it always creates a new element

   // where's the set() method on firebase-collection?
   // something like this.$.myfb.set(key, updatedObj) would be handy.
}
```

Comment: Try using `e.model.set('dinosaur.height', 'new value to be set')`, that sets it properly so that it's picked by polymer's data binding and that should trigger the `firebase-collection` update sequence

Comment: AH... this worked. Thank you. upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alan pointed out in comments, this worked with the firebase-collection:

```
e.model.set('dinosaur.height', 'new value to be set')
```

also, the one-way data binding for items=[[dinosaurs]] was changed to a two-way binding as in items={{dinosaurs}}. I didn't expect this to affect the firebase coupling, but it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the firebase document to update data, it can be mapped to a location on firebase like so:

```
<firebase-document
  location="https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs"
  data="{{dinosaurs}}"></firebase-document>
```

> A  is a reference to a remote document somewhere on Firebase. The element fetchs a document at a provided location, and exposes it as an Object that is suitable for deep two-way databinding.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-document

Comment: Here is an example I found somewhere, not sure who made it though: http://jsbin.com/lokegu/12/edit?html,output